# Postgres - Query one to many relationship

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make a query to get a `report` and all of the `report_items` associated with the report.

`reports` table structure: id | name | creation_date

`report_items` table structure: id | report_id | place | producer | serial_number

I tried this:

```
SELECT "reports".*,
          to_json("report_items".*) as "items"
          FROM "reports" INNER JOIN "report_items" USING ("id")
          WHERE "reports".id = ${req.params.id}
```

but only the first report_item returns (instead of a list of report_items):

```
{"id":1,"type":"fd","name":"dsfdsfds","client_name":"fdsfds","website":"dsffds","creation_time":"2019-03-12T22:00:00.000Z","items":{"id":1,"report_id":1,"place":"saddsa","type":"sdadsa","producer":"sdadsa","serial_number":"adsdsa","next_check_date":"2019-03-19","test_result":"saddsa","comments":"saddsa"}}
```

Expected result:

```
{"id":1,"type":"fd","name":"dsfdsfds","client_name":"fdsfds","website":"dsffds","creation_time":"2019-03-12T22:00:00.000Z","items": [{"id":1,"report_id":1,"place":"saddsa","type":"sdadsa","producer":"sdadsa","serial_number":"adsdsa","next_check_date":"2019-03-19","test_result":"saddsa","comments":"saddsa"}, {"id":1,"report_id":1,"place":"saddsa","type":"sdadsa","producer":"sdadsa","serial_number":"adsdsa","next_check_date":"2019-03-19","test_result":"saddsa","comments":"saddsa"}]}
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

---

a long solution I can do (pretty sure it's not ideal..):

```
SELECT * FROM reports
        WHERE id = ${req.params.id}

SELECT * FROM report_items
      WHERE report_id = ${req.params.id}
```

and combine them programmatically.

Comment: Add table definition of reports, report_items, sample data and expected result.

Comment: This line of code is taking your id from the input and only returning that value - WHERE "reports".id = ${req.params.id}

Comment: You don't aggregate the items into a single JSON array. For a report with multiple "items" you will get more than one row. I interpret the example output you gave as a single full row after external conversion to JSON. Just try wrapping the `to_json` into an array aggregation, e.g.: `array_to_json(array_agg(to_json(report_items.*))) AS items`

Comment: @KaushikNayak I added the table definitions and expected result.

Comment: @Ancoron Got an error - `Error: error: column "reports.id" must appear in
 the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
`

Comment: Of course, when you want to have all items combined into an array for one report in only a single output row, then you actually _aggregate_. Let me provide an answer to have that one sorted out as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, the desired result is a single row for the report data including all items as a JSON array.

Under that assumption, a query as follows should work:

```sql
WITH data (id, items) AS (
    SELECT report_id, array_to_json(array_agg(to_json(*)))
    FROM report_items WHERE report_id = ${req.params.id}
    GROUP BY report_id
)
SELECT reports.*, data.items
FROM reports
INNER JOIN data ON (reports.id = data.report_id)
WHERE reports.id = ${req.params.id}
```

...or as a sub-select (because PostgreSQL is not yet smart enough to push down the filter into the CTE:

```sql
SELECT reports.*, data.items
FROM reports
INNER JOIN (SELECT report_id, array_to_json(array_agg(to_json(report_items.*)))
    FROM report_items
    GROUP BY report_id) AS data (id, items) ON (reports.id = data.id)
WHERE reports.id = ${req.params.id}
```

In both cases, the output column `items` will contain a JSON array of all related items.

If you want the complete report entry as JSON, try this (beware this only works for `jsonb`, not `json`):

```sql
SELECT jsonb_set(to_jsonb(reports.*), '{items}', data.items, true) AS report_data
FROM reports
INNER JOIN (SELECT report_id, array_to_json(array_agg(to_json(report_items.*)))::jsonb
    FROM report_items
    GROUP BY report_id) AS data (id, items) ON (reports.id = data.id)
WHERE reports.id = ${req.params.id}
```